Excel automate dynamic number of row generation from another set of data
I am trying to automate for dynamic number of rows to be created from a reference data.
So there are 2 sheets - Sheet1 and Sheet2.
What I want is by referring to Sheet1 (column E i.e. ROLE_ID ) and then under Sheet2 (Column ROLE_ID), it should dynamically create that many number of rows (as there are in Sheet1 - Column E i.e. ROLE_ID)
Thus, it would first create 8 rows for GROUP A, then 5 rows for GROUP B and then 8 rows for GROUP C.
Below is how my Sheet1 looks (which is kind of my reference data);

and below is my Sheet2 (where I want to add the dynamic rows from Sheet1);

Not sure if it is possible to automate such thing using Excel formulas.
UPDATED
Below is my expected output (in Sheet2)

=FILTER(J4:J186, IF(ISBLANK(J4:J186), TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(J4:J186), TRUE, IF(ISNA(J4:J186), FALSE, TRUE))))
=LET(
a, Sheet1!K4:K186,
b, TAKE(a,,-1),
c, SCAN(0,b,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>0,x,x+1)))+1,
d, Sheet2!C7:F36,
IF(b="","",HSTACK(b, CHOOSEROWS(d, XMATCH(c, SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)))))))
=LET(
a, Sheet1!K4:K186,
b, TAKE(a,,-1),
c, SCAN(0,b,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>0,x,x+1)))+1,
d, Sheet2!C7:F36,
IF(b=0, "", IF(b="", "", HSTACK(b, CHOOSEROWS(d, XMATCH(c, SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)))))))
)
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G4)), G4, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E4)), E4, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C4)), C4, "")))
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G4:G196)), G4:G196, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E4:E196)), E4:E196, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C4:C196)), C4:C196, "")))
=VLOOKUP(H4, Roles!$B$30:Roles!$C$54, 2, FALSE)
=IF(H4<>"", VLOOKUP(H4, Roles!$B$30:Roles!$C$54, 2, FALSE), "")
=IF(H4:H196<>"", FILTER(Roles!$C$30:$C$54, Roles!$B$30:$B$54=H4:H196), "")
=IF(H4<>"", VLOOKUP(H4, Roles!$B$30:$C$54, 2, FALSE), "")
=IF(C7:C202=0,"","INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COL1,COL2) values('"&C7:C202&"','"&D7:D202&"');")
=IF(OR(C7:C202=0, ISBLANK(C7:C202)), "", "INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COL1,COL2) values('"&C7:C202&"','"&D7:D202&"');")
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(10), A1)), ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(13), A1))), "Contains CR or LF", "Does not contain CR or LF")
=IF(C7:C202=0,"","INSERT")
=IF(C31="","empty cell",IF(C31=0,"Zero Cell","Cell > Zero"))
=IF(C7:C202="", "", IF(C7:C202=0, "", "INSERT"))
=LET(
range1, Sheet1!A1:A20,
range2, Sheet2!B5:B25,
range3, Sheet3!C10:C30,
combined, VSTACK(range1, range2, range3),
INDEX(combined, SEQUENCE(ROWS(combined)))
)

Could you show your expected output please, and can you use FILTER() function like =LET(a, FILTER(Sheet1!D6:E28,Sheet1!E6:E28<>""), IF(a=0,"",a)) and where does the ROLE_NAME comes from, please explain! And if you want to fill the blank rows of GROUP then =LET(a, FILTER(Sheet1!D6:E28,Sheet1!E6:E28<>""), HSTACK(TAKE(a,,-1),SCAN(0,TAKE(a,,1),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=0,r,c)))))

@MayukhBhattacharya - Thanks...I have updated with my expected output. For now, we can just focus on the ROLE_ID column (as I am basically looking to generate that many number of dynamic rows in Sheet2)

Try using the following: =IF(Sheet1!E6:E28=0,"",Sheet1!E6:E28) You are just referencing that many rows in the sheet one to sheet 2, just use the one i have mentioned, IF() is not required it is only used to hide the 0 to show as "" empty!

Yes right...basically in Sheet1, there will be empty rows to kind of indicate that the particular group has ended and then a new group will begin...I am fine to have that same empty row in Sheet2

Please use the one I have commented!

Thanks...this is really awesome...I just had one last related question

Yes what is it?

I just updated in the original question...it is about using Sheet3 for dynamically filling ROLE_NAME and ROLE_GROUP columns in Sheet2

Also, I am fine to use manually add and use some character in ROLE_ID column to identify the separation of groups (instead of empty row)

@MayukhBhattacharya - Also, it would be really great if you can add as an answer and I can accept the same. Thanks again

Related questions are new questions and get their own new thread. If the current question has been answered, then mark this thread as such please.

@JvdV Sir, it is my fault, I should have asked OP, but I thought it was related to the IF() part, I wasn;t sure that they were going to change the question.

Here is one way of doing the same:


=LET(
     a, Sheet1!D6:E28,
     b, TAKE(a,,-1),
     c, SCAN(0,b,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>"",x,x+1)))+1,
     d, Sheet3!D4:E6,
     IF(b="","",HSTACK(b, CHOOSEROWS(d, XMATCH(c, SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)))))))


Explanations:

Using LET() function it helps to define variables and reduce redundant calculations.
Variable a is defines the data from Sheet1 --> Sheet1!D6:E28
Variable b is defines the second column range of data taken from  a using TAKE() function, so using TAKE(a,,-1) returns the specific range.
Next, Variable c uses a LAMBDA() helper function called SCAN() which helps in returning an array with the help of the custom formula applied to the LAMBDA() which iterates through each value in the array and returns an array of outputs for each intermediate element in the array. So, it checks for the b if the range is not empty and fills the value from above, its like we do usually using the fill values from above same way but using dynamically !
Next, the variable d refers to the data from Sheet3
Finally using a simple XMATCH() to match the numbers of rows in sheet 3 data with the variable c and using CHOOSEROWS() to fill the respective data and lastly to keep and maintain the formatting of blanks we are using IF() to parse those out.



Thanks again...if you could just give a very brief explanation of what the formula does, that would be really helpful...just few words would also help in understanding

For some reason, I am getting #N/A printed when I use the above formula

@copenndthagen not sure how you get those #N/A, because it is working on my end, are you having the same set as shown in the OP, may be differences in the data context but the layout resembles same right?

Yeah...The other formula you gave works perfectly i.e. =IF(Sheet1!E6:E28=0,"",Sheet1!E6:E28)
But  when I try the =LET(.......) one, it prints #N/A

I am not able to say, it works on my end!

I assume I just need to paste this =LET(.......) formula wher I want my first row/column to be printed and the subsequent rows/columns would get printed dynamically

@copenndthagen may be you might need to suit the ranges, but the logic remains same here! This is the Excel you can check!

@copenndthagen you dont have to use the other formula anymore now, just use the present one.

Are you considering Sheet1 - Column D (GROUP) for anything...I am fine to ignore that column

@copenndthagen yes to keep everything and make it dynamic i have included everything, click on the excel, i have added to see, it will help!

First cell under "ROLE_ID" in Sheet2:
=LET(
    comment_1, "Range from first row to the possible last row (5000)",
    role_id_col, Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5000,
    comment_2, "IFS non-empty = row number, #NA otherwise; TOCOL to remove #NA",
    row_num, TOCOL(IFS(LEN(TRIM(role_id_col)), ROW(role_id_col)), 2),
    comment_3, "Assuming header (ROLE_ID) is the first non-empty cell, set the range",
    role_id_data, INDEX(role_id_col, MIN(row_num) + 1):INDEX(role_id_col, MAX(row_num)),
    comment_4, "Replace empty cells with empty string (these will be 0 otherwise)",
    IF(LEN(TRIM(role_id_data)), role_id_data, "")
)

